# ReferenceError : Can't find variable React - React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using the DrawerNavigation component of React Navigation. I am passing a custom Drawer Screen using it's [contentComponent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html) property. However, I keep getting following error:

[image]

I am aware, we are not supposed to post screenshots of the code but I couldn't figure out a way to copy stack trace off simulator.

I checked the DrawerSidebar.js file and it seems to be importing React explicitly. I am using the latest version of react-navigation and this is the [file](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/Drawer/DrawerSidebar.js) that seems to causing the error.

Comment: I think you might forget to import the React in js file . case I face same error problem import React from 'react';

Answer (score 5):

You have to import react into your navigation component where createDrawerNavigator() defined. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your custom component may be .jsx.

.jsx needs to import React because of its syntax sugar.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

> Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the React.createElement(component, props, ...children) function
>
> ```
> <MyButton color="blue" shadowSize={2}>
>   Click Me
> </MyButton>
> ```
>
> compiles into:
>
> ```
> React.createElement(
>    MyButton,
>    {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
>    'Click Me'
> )
> ```
>
> React Must Be in Scope
>
> Since JSX compiles into calls to React.createElement, the React library must also always be in scope from your JSX code.